# awk search command for case-insensitivy

Tags: sed, awk, grep, cut

I have the following awk commmand..i want to make "issue-Fixed" as case-insensitive,can anyone provide inputs on how this can be done,i looked at http://www.unix.com/shell-programming-scripting/20196-case-insensitive-serach-awk.html but this doesnt seem to work for me

```
awk '/link|issue-Fixed:/{print $2}' foo.txt | sed 'N; y/\n/ /'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might work for you:

```
awk '/link|[Ii][Ss][Ss][Uu][Ee]-[Ff][Ii][Xx][Ee][Dd]:/{print $2}' foo.txt | sed 'N; y/\n/ /'
```